# Proving an inequality which looks like we could use Bernoulli's inequality

Tags: inequality, binomial-coefficients

How can we prove this inequality:
$$\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n<3$$
What I did is:
$$(1+\frac{1}{n})^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}1^{(n-k)}\frac{1}{n^k}=$$
$$1+\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{n^k}$$
I got stuck here, I have to prove that $\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{n^k}<2$
Could you give me a hint?

Comment: You could use $\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{n^k} \leqslant \frac{1}{k!}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer That seems to make sense, but how could that help me?

Comment: You can estimate $$\sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}$$ pretty easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at $$L(x) = \ln f(x) = n \ln \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)$$ and note that it is increasing and that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} L(x) = 1$$ (which you can show by L'Hospital's rule, for example).

Since $\ln 3 > 1$, we conclude that $L(x) \ge 1 < \ln 3$ and thus exponentiating yields $$f(x) = e^{L(x)} < e^{\ln 3} = 3$$ as desired.

Comment: Thank you, one more question: Could you just explain me why $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{2^k}=2-\frac{1}{2^{n}}$?

Comment: @A6Tech This about itm here is a hint: $$\frac{1}{2^k} + \frac{1}{2^k} = \frac{2}{2^k} = \frac{1}{2^{k-1}}.$$ so for example $$\frac{1}{16} + \left(\frac{1}{16} + \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{2} + 1 \right) = 2$$ If you are into doing this quickly, just sum the geometric series on the left-hand side